# Multiprocessing POST request in Python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

I need help with multiprocessing.

I have no experience with this and I don't know how accurate it is. I made a post request for an api to update the backend. I know there is a way to send multiple driver_id's to update there status and I am looking for help on how to divide these driver_id's and send it in chunks.
Let's say I have to update data for 10000 drivers within a min how can I achieve this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is a post request:

```
import requests

url = "https://api.xyz.com/v1/test/drivers/{12345666}/daily_status/duty_status"

payload = {
    "status": "ON_DUTY",
    "remark": "testing",
    "time": 1670009505000
}
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "authorization": "#########"
}

response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

Currently I am using for loop to loop over the list of dict and get the driver_id and make a post request.

```
for i in details:
    url = post_url.format(i['driver_id'])
    payload = {
        "status": i['status_type'],
        "remark": i['remark'],
        "time": i['time']
    }
    response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
```

Comment: With multiprocessing, you can create a pool of workers that hit the function and return output using `pool.imap()` so all you have to do is generate a list of input and pass onto function. " I have to update data for 10000 drivers within a min" might be a bit more expectation as it would mean rougly 167 requests/sec so you need some robust API backend and a good CPU/Network to handle this load.

Comment: Also look into `multithreading` vs `multiprocessing`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `httpx` instead of `requests` to send many simultaneous requests.

Example, calling dummy API, it can handle up to 1500 requests in-flight (after that API temporally bans me)

If you need to send requests even faster you can combine async with `multiprocessing.Pool` but speedup will probably be pretty modest compated to single-threaded async.

```
import asyncio

import httpx


async def perform_many_calls_simultaneously(data_chunk: list[int]):
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        coroutines = [client.get(f"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/{value}") for value in data_chunk]
        res = await asyncio.gather(*coroutines)
        print(len(res))



data = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25]]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for data_chunk in data:
        asyncio.run(perform_many_calls_simultaneously(data_chunk))

# from multiprocessing import Pool
#
"""Porabably even faster vatiant"""
#
# def run_loop(data_chunk: list[int]):
#    asyncio.run(perform_many_calls_simultaneously(data_chunk))
#
# if __name__ == '__main__':
#    with Pool(3) as p:
#        p.map(run_loop, data)
```